# Using theories in junit to create a list of all possible results?

Tags: java, junit, junit-theory

I've been using theories before to try different entries for how to set values for an object in jUnit.

Now I am facing this issue,

I want to do the same using theories and create different objects with all the possible answers but THEN group them all in a list to later pass other test (assertions).

I tried to make an empty list and add elements by calling a private method that runs with a theory and uses the entry points but doesnt work... like this:

```
@DataPoints("ids")
public static String[] eventIds = {"123", "1234"};

@Theory
private Object test(@FromDataPoints("ids") final String id) {
  return new Object(id);
}
```

and then

```
@Test
private void finalTest() {
  List<Object> objects = new ArrayList<Object>();
  objects.add(test()); //<==== CANNOT DO THIS
}
```

any idea how to archive this?

At the end I want to get a List with all possible objects (in this case only 2)

Comment: if I understand you correctly, your list would have to be in a static field

Comment: Yes, it could be a static field, but I cannot fill it in a proper way, any idea?